# Check if an Object already exists in Room

Tags: android, android-room

this might be a stupid question but I cant seem to find the way to see if an object in my database already exists or not. In this case I want to check if the user with everything exists already, check the password with the hashed one and return the Result.

```
private fun getLoginResult(username: String, password: String): Result<LiveData<BudgetyUser>> {

    try{
        val user = dataSource.getUser(username)
        val passwordDB = user.value?.userPassword
        val saltDB = user.value?.userSalt
        if(user.value == null){
            return Result.ErrorUserNotFound("User $username not found.")
        }
        if (!hashStringSha512(password, saltDB!!).contentEquals(passwordDB!!)) {
            return Result.ErrorWrongPassword("Wrong password.")
        }
        return Result.Success(user)
    } catch (e: SQLiteConstraintException){
        return Result.ErrorUserNotFound("User $username not found.")
    }
    catch (e: Throwable) {
        return Result.LoginException(IOException("Error logging in", e))
    }
}
```

The dataSource is my DatabasDAO that returns a LiveData Object, but its always null. I try to just get a user by the provided username, and if the returned object is null, no user with that name exists. At least that is the way I wanted it to work. Any Idea how to make it work like that?

Thanks in Advance!

PS. Couldnt find and answer that was what I needed.

```
interface UserDBDao {

    @Insert
    fun insert(user: BudgetyUser)

    @Update
    fun update(user: BudgetyUser)

    @Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = :username")
    fun getUser(username: String) : LiveData<BudgetyUser>


    @Query("DELETE FROM users")
    fun deleteUsers()



}
```

Comment: Can you post your DAO?

Comment: Its up. But this worked like this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't extract data from a `LiveData` straight from its value, you should rather observe it. Example:

```
val userLiveData = dataSource.getUser(username)
userLiveData.observe(this, Observer { user ->
    // Handle user data here
}
```

Now if you want to find out whether an entry is present on your database you should use `COUNT()` on your DAO. Example:

```
@QUERY("SELECT COUNT() FROM BudgetyUser WHERE id = :id")
fun count(id: Int): Int
```

Then, to find out whether the user you're looking for is in your database, just check if the result of your DAO's `count` function is greater than 0.

Comment: Thank you very much! 
But I cant use an Observer in my Repository since I Dont have a LifecycleOwner there .

Comment: The repository's responsibility should be only to abstract the fetching of data, either from a local data source, a remote one or both then return whatever result it received to the ViewModel. Then, the ViewModel will simply return what it received from the repository so that the UI can observe it

Comment: Ahh alright, got it. My mistake trying to check the password within the repository then.

Comment: How we can check on main thread if data exist or not if not then store value?

Comment: The check must* inevitably happen on another thread, whose result you'll need to observe on the main thread and then act on it.

* Or else your app will crash as Android doesn't allow running IO operations on the main thread